# $\int y^{2}dx+x^{2}dy$ and $C\left( r\right) =\left(a \cos t,b\sin t\right)$

Tags: calculus

$\int y^{2}dx+x^{2}dy$ and $C\left( r\right) =\left(a \cos t,b\sin t\right)$ ,$0<t< \pi$

Could someone give me a hint to evaluate this integral?

my efforts:
$C^{'}\left( r\right)=\left(-a \sin t,b\cos t\right)$ then $\left\| C^{'}\left( r\right) \right\|$=$\sqrt {a^{2}\sin ^{2}t+b^{2}\cos ^{2}t}$ then I didn't get anywhere from here. Should I employ Green's theorem?

Comment: Let $x=a\cos t$ and $y=b\sin t$ and replace in integral.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x(t)=a \cos t$ and $y(t)= b \sin t$.

Then $\int_C y^{2}dx+x^{2}dy=\int_0^{\pi}(y(t)^2 x'(t)+x(t)^2 y'(t)) dt.$

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Perhaps he/she thought your answer worth no more than a vote

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=a\cos t$ and $y=b\sin t$ and replace in integral. Therefore
\begin{align}
\int y^{2}dx+x^{2}dy
&= \int_0^\pi (b\sin t)^2(-a\sin t)\ dt + (a\cos t)^2(b\cos t)\ dt \\
&= ab\int_0^\pi (a\cos^3t-b\sin^3t)\ dt \\
&= \color{blue}{-\dfrac43ab^2}
\end{align}

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Revenge. Wow ...

Comment: i didnt do . i cant use vote because my reputation less than 15.

Comment: @user582369 Never mind. I said that for fun :)

Comment: could you solve the problem?

Comment: yes. actually you solved :)